# Camera vs world calibration

Tags: ros, calibration, pose, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all!
I'm successfully using a "home made" stereo head to obtain a disparity image with the package stereo_image_proc.

Now I'm trying to calculate the position of the camera in the world frame, possibly using a checkerboard where the first cross represents the world origin.
I've tried to use the camera_pose_calibration package without success.

Do you know others methods that you can suggest me?

I'm particulary interested in online methods where the camera automatically calibrates itself by looking at the checkerboard.

Many thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/39762/camera-vs-world-calibration/) by [oleo80](https://answers.ros.org/users/2184/oleo80/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2012-07-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you have the intrinsics of just one camera, you should be able to use `FindExtrinsicCameraParams`, which will give the rotation and translation between the checkerboard frame and the camera frame

Check out [opencv docs](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/python/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html) for more info

---

Originally posted by [phil0stine](https://answers.ros.org/users/639/phil0stine/) with karma: 682 on 2012-07-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [oleo80](https://answers.ros.org/users/2184/oleo80/) on 2012-07-25**:
Thanks for your answer! I'm looking at the openCV documentation right now.
Would have been better if there was a package of ROS already implemented! :-)

**Comment by [phil0stine](https://answers.ros.org/users/639/phil0stine/) on 2012-07-25**:
In a way there is a package for that, its really what `camera_pose_calibration` is intended to do. If it isn't working for you, maybe a quick opencv python script (subscribe to image and cam info, get the extrinsics, publish to /tf) will be the fastest way to make progress.

**Comment by [oleo80](https://answers.ros.org/users/2184/oleo80/) on 2012-07-26**:
I've found another great package! http://www.ros.org/wiki/ar_pose
It works perfectly with special markers.

**Comment by [Athoesen](https://answers.ros.org/users/8296/athoesen/) on 2014-01-09**:
Do you think this package could be used to calibrate multiple Kinects?